# wpf - Get values from App Config file

Tags: wpf, appsettings, configurationmanager

How to get values from App.Config.

Code:

```
 <configuration>
  <appSettings>
   <add key="ShowRoomCode" value="1000"/>
   <add key="FolderPath" value="D:\\Images\\Book\\"/>
  </appSettings>
 </configuration>

 string imageFolderPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FolderPath"];
```

But it returns null value. Config file is in the Same project.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you expand the **Properties** section of Visual Studio and double click the settings section, you will be able to add custom settings which end up like so in the config file:

```
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
        <section name="WpfApplication1.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<userSettings>
    <WpfApplication1.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="FilePath" serializeAs="String">
            <value>Thing</value>
        </setting>
    </WpfApplication1.Properties.Settings>
</userSettings>
</configuration>
```

Which you can then do this in your code:

```
string thing = Properties.Settings.Default.FilePath;
```

Which is nice because it gives you type safety too

Comment: Solution Explorer -> MyProject -> Properties Folder -> Settings.Settings" (VS2012)

Comment: Above does not work for me, alternatively I used this:

YourAppName.Properties.Settings.Default.NameOfYourSetting.ToString();

Answer (score 1):

The code you wrote should work - make sure you haven't changed 'BuildAction' of the config file.